# No authentication token when another controller action is rendered in the template

Tags: php, symfony

I have a template which contains `{{ render(controller(...) }}` code. It works fine until I try to process 404 error. I'm getting `The security context contains no authentication token` trying to invoke controller action even though the result it returns contains single line of text and doesn't use session or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you rendered template (not only the subrequest, but the container and additional includes aswell) contains any references to `{{ app.user }}`. Quoting from the official documentation:

> You must not use is_granted in your error pages (or layout used by
>   your error pages), because the router runs before the firewall. If the
>   router throws an exception (for instance, when the route does not
>   match), then using is_granted will throw a further exception. You can
>   use is_granted safely by saying {% if app.user and is_granted('...')
>   %}.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

Comment: It's the first thing I checked as I already had troubles with it. It seems to be very common mistake. But this time I checked and localized the error. I have no problems with the template at all, error appears only when I invoke an action and when I hide it it works fine. And my subrequest is quite simple only making some Memcache requests and returning text line.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide an action"?

Comment: I mean remove the call, comment the string in template.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Do you have any service that depends on the `@security.context` one?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I still have it when I don't render an action.